# Excel UDF Text Join Combinig two columns

Tags: excel

I am new here and this is my first question. I have created a UDF text join function. but it only combine first range then second range if cells.

Whereas I want it should get value of cell 1 from colum 1 and then combine it with cell 1 of column 2 then again combine cell 2 of column 1 and cell 2 of column 2 and so on.

Moreover if data in coulmn 1 is available but not in column2 then it should get value of cell 1 of column 2 and combine it with for example cell 14 of column 1.

Hope I am clear.

```
Column 1      column2
A               1
B               2
C               3
D               4
E
F
G
```

And output should be

```
A1B2C3D4E1F2G3
```

Thanks in advance

My Code is as under

```
Function Text_Join(delimiter As String, Ignore_Empty As Boolean, ParamArray text() As Variant)
   Dim Rg As Variant 
   Dim rgCell As Variant
   Dim amal As Range 
   Dim i As Long 
   Dim NewArray() As Variant
   
   i = 0
   
   For Each Rg In text
       If TypeName(Rg) = "Range" Then
           For Each rgCell In Rg
           If Not Ignore_Empty Or Not IsEmpty(rgCell) Then
                ReDim Preserve NewArray(i)
                NewArray(i) = rgCell
                i = i + 1
           End If
           Next
       Else
           If Not Ignore_Empty Or Not IsEmpty(rgCell) Then
           ReDim Preserve NewArray(i)
           NewArray(i) = Rg
           i = i + 1
           End If
       End If
    Next    
    Text_Join = Join(NewArray, delimiter) 
End Function
```

Comment: Can you [edit] your question with your code?

Comment: You will need to modify your existing UDF, if it is not doing what you want.

Comment: First of all Thank you so much for your response. I have edited and pasted my code, pl

Comment: What if column 1 has less items than column 2?

Answer (score 1):

To help you solving your problem, i made some changes to your code (at end of line, you see 'Added or Removed or Changed.

```
Function Text_Join(delimiter As String, Ignore_Empty As Boolean, text As Range) 'Changed
   Dim Rg As Variant
   Dim rgCell As Variant
   Dim amal As Range
   Dim i As Long
   Dim NewArray() As Variant
   Dim Result As String 'Added
   
   i = 0
   
   For Each Rg In text
       If TypeName(Rg) = "Range" Then
           For Each rgCell In Rg
           If Not Ignore_Empty Or Not IsEmpty(rgCell) Or rgCell.text <> "" Then 'Changed
                'ReDim Preserve NewArray(i)   'Removed
                'NewArray(i) = rgCell         'Removed
                'i = i + 1                    'Removed
                Result = Result + rgCell.text 'Added
           Else                               'Added
                Result = Result + "X"         'Added
           End If
           Next
       Else
           If Not Ignore_Empty Or Not IsEmpty(rgCell) Then
           ReDim Preserve NewArray(i)
           NewArray(i) = Rg
           i = i + 1
           End If
       End If
    Next
    'Text_Join = Join(NewArray, delimiter)   'Removed
    Text_Join = Result
End Function
```

I tested with `=Text_Join("";TRUE;A2:B8)`

Output is: `A1B2C3D4EXFXGX`

I hope you have enough skills to solve the rest of your problem  Suc6!

Comment: Thank you si.much. Rest I will do it.